# What "problem" did the OP face when he posted this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

I have a very simple question.

What problem did the OP face when he posted this question:

[What's the correlation between guys with longer hair and professionalism?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/whats-the-correlation-between-guys-with-longer-hair-and-professionalism)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

THe problem is stated directly in the question:

> For awhile now, my higher-ups have been saying bugging me to get a hair cut.. Though, I like it how it is.

The user was wondering why such pressure would exist in the workplace, and if there was any cause for it. The highest-scored answer explains a lack of concrete evidence about a link (or absence of a link) between long hair and professionalism, and makes up for that lack of information by providing relevant information from personal experience.

And again, this question was asked early in the beta period. The community was more concerned with getting quality, on-topic content than with enforcing the **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face** rule. In fact, if you read the next sentence in the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

you'll see that it doesn't disallow such questions. While having the potential to be chatty and open-ended, the question is well-worded, and has a great answer.

Answer (score 7):

All quotes are directly from the original question. We can discuss whether the problem is meaningful or not but:

---

> For awhile now, my higher-ups have been saying bugging me to get a hair cut..

Situation

> Though, I like it how it is.

Conflict (or problem).

> Could someone try to kindly explain this to me?

Question related to the problem.

Comment: -1 It's not a real problem if there wasn't any slapping involved.

Comment: /me slaps @Yannis

Comment: @Yannis - But i am pretty sure that the long hair was seen as an attempt to sleep with the bosses wife.

Comment: @Chad he only grew long hair because his boss slapped him for getting the reports wrong

Answer (score -4):

The OP didn't face an actual problem, but this question cannot be closed for two reasons:

1. It currently has a net of 21 upvotes.
2. It was asked last June.

By themselves, neither of these reasons is enough to keep the question open, but when paired together, they *are* enough to keep the question open.

Why?

StackExchange sites certainly aren't afraid to close popular non-constructive questions, but popular questions must be closed immediately. If they're not, then they tend to pick up constructive answers which bolster the question's perceived "answerability" and solidifies their case for remaining open.

Comment: Are you suggesting it's a bad thing that "they tend to pick up constructive answers"?

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is attempting to answer your question here. You asked "what is the problem" and not "should this question be closed."

Comment: @Jim: No, I'm not. I'm pointing it out as fact because some questions, if left alone for a short period of time, can in fact earn constructive answers and improve their perceived "answerability".

Comment: @enderland: That's true. But if we agree that the OP really didn't face a problem, then the next logical question would be - "Well then why didn't the community vote to close?" And I'm offering a good explanation as to why the community didn't vote to close this question.

Comment: @JimG. If a question attracts good, constructive answers, then it stands to reason that there is a good, constructive question being asked. If it doesn't appear that way, the question might have a wording/scope problem, which can probably be solved with an edit.

Comment: @Jim: You're right. And as I've said before, jmort253 has been doing a terrific job with edits and gentle advice; nudging questions back to an acceptable form.

Comment: As a side note, the question can be closed, thats what closed votes are for. Also the number of upvotes is irrelevant to whether or not something is eligible for closing. Its more of a correlation than causation

Comment: @RhysW: A very valid point.